# Scheduled Toast Notification Alarm loop

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm working with Toast and I successfully create scheduled toast that show up after specific time. But I have a problem with Audio, my goal is to make this sound in the loop unitl the user press button, but when I set the Loop parameter to true, my toast didn't work. My system is Windows 10 build 10240.

```
ToastContent content = new ToastContent()
{
    Duration = ToastDuration.Long,
    Visual = new ToastVisual()
    {
        TitleText = new ToastText()
        {
            Text = "Alarm"
        },

        BodyTextLine1 = new ToastText()
        {
            Text = "Wake up"
        }
    },
    Scenario = ToastScenario.Reminder,
    Audio = new ToastAudio()
    {
        Src = new Uri("ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm"),
        Loop = true,
        Silent = false
    },
    Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
    {
        Buttons =
        {
           new ToastButtonSnooze(),
           new ToastButtonDismiss()
        }
    }
};

ScheduledToastNotification toast = new ScheduledToastNotification(content.GetXml(), dueTime);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(toast);
```

**Edit**
Loop works when I write my toast as xml. So that is the solution

Xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toast duration="long" scenario="alarm">
  <visual>
    <binding template="ToastGeneric" >
      <text> Daily .Net Tips </text>
    </binding>
   </visual>
  <audio src="ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm" loop="true">
  </audio>
  <actions>
  <action activationType="system" arguments="snooze" content=""/>
  <action activationType="system" arguments="dismiss" content=""/>
  </actions>
  </toast>
```

C# code

```
        string xmlString = File.ReadAllText(@"ToastTemplate\AlarmTemplate.xml");
        Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument toastDOM = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
        toastDOM.LoadXml(xmlString);

        var toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
        toastNotifier.Show(new ToastNotification(toastDOM));
```

Comment: does it work with your `Buttons =
        {
           new ToastButtonSnooze(),
           new ToastButtonDismiss()
        }`?
Shouldn't you use `new ...`?

Comment: Everything is good until I set Loop = true

Comment: What does Loop do?  I don't see its declaration nor its implementation anywhere

Comment: @MateuszHufnagiel may I please know how are you repeating the alarm everyday?

Answer (score 2):

This is Andrew from the Notifications team on Microsoft.

Since you are using Scenario = Alarm, you **do not need to set Duration or Loop**.

The Alarm scenario will automatically keep the toast on the user's screen until they take action, so setting Duration = Long is useless.

Also, the Alarm scenario will automatically loop audio, so setting Loop = true is useless.

Here's what your updated code should be like (make sure you're setting the scenario to Alarm, I noticed you had Reminder in your original code)...

```cs
ToastContent content = new ToastContent()
{
    Visual = new ToastVisual()
    {
        TitleText = new ToastText()
        {
            Text = "Alarm"
        },

        BodyTextLine1 = new ToastText()
        {
            Text = "Wake up"
        }
    },
    Scenario = ToastScenario.Alarm,
    Audio = new ToastAudio()
    {
        Src = new Uri("ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm")
    },
    Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
    {
        Buttons =
        {
           new ToastButtonSnooze(),
           new ToastButtonDismiss()
        }
    }
};
```

As for why the toast was breaking via NotificationsExtensions rather than raw XML... it looks like you found a bug in NotificationsExtensions.

I updated NotificationsExtensions.Win10 today to address this bug, version 10586.0.2 has the fix (or version 10240.0.8 if you're still using the 10240 versions). Details of the fix are in [this code commit](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/NotificationsExtensions/commit/c4549bde7bec02eeb91c629d34e8d5805ee937bc) if you're curious.